# Coefficients of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: functions, elementary-functions, chebyshev-polynomials

Not long ago, I derived the formula for Chebyshev polynomials

$$T_{n}\left( x\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}x^{n-2k}\left( x^2-1\right)^{k}$$
How to extract the coefficients of this polynomial of degree $n$ ?

I tried using Newton's binomial but got a double sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}x^{n-2k}\left(  \sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} x^{2m}\left( -1\right)^{k-m}  \right) \\
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\left( -1\right)^{k-m} {n \choose 2k}  \cdot {k \choose m} x^{n+2m-2k}\\
 $$

Now how to continue counting this sum ?
What would it look like to change the order of summation and would it do anything ?

What else did I try ?

Well, I worked out the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor  \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}{n \choose 2k}x^{n-2k}\left( x^2-1\right)^{k} $$

for $n=8$
and I hypothesized that
$$T_{n}\left( x\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}  \sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\left( -1\right)^{k}{n \choose 2m}  \cdot {m \choose k} x^{n-2k} $$
However, it would be useful to demonstrate the correctness of this hypothesis and count the sum of
$$\sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}{n \choose 2m}  \cdot {m \choose k}$$
Here I would like to point out that Wolfram Alpha counts this sum incorrectly
$$\sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}{{n \choose 2m} \cdot  {m \choose k}}  = \frac{n}{2n-2k}  \cdot 2^{n-2k} \cdot {n - k \choose k}$$

And it would even be a nice result but
first of all it is not quite correct ( Have you noticed why ?)
and secondly it comes from a hypothesis I made after dissecting the formula for $n=8$.

It seems to me that this hypothesis of mine would be enough to prove by induction after n but how would it look?

How to calculate the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomial ?
Are you sure they will be the sum of products of Bernoulli numbers and Newton symbol
since, after working out the formula, I came out that it would be
$$T_{n}\left( x\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}  \sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\left( -1\right)^{k} {n \choose 2m} \cdot  {m \choose k}  x^{n-2k}$$

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked if your conjectured form works for other values of $n$? like $n=6,7$ ecc.

Comment: I have not checked for $n=6$ , $7$ but the correctness for$ n=0$ and $n=1$ is immediately apparent, I suspect that induction after n would be enough 
only I do not know how it would look like

Comment: Nobody can help me?